# how do i create a new object based off an array and another object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs, object

I am trying to create a new object based off an existing array. I want to create a new object that show below

```
{ jack: 'jack', content: 'ocean'},
{ marie: 'marie', content: 'pond'},
{ james: 'james', content: 'fish biscuit'},
{paul: 'paul', content: 'cake'}
```

```js
const words = ['jack','marie','james','paul']

const myUsers = [
    { name: 'jack', likes: 'ocean' },
    { name: 'marie', likes: 'pond' },
    { name: 'james', likes: 'fish biscuits' },
    { name: 'paul', likes: 'cake' }
]

const usersByLikes = words.map(word => {
    const container = {};
    

    container[word] = myUsers.map(user => user.name);
    container.content = myUsers[0].likes;

    return container;
})
```

I am not getting the correct object, but instead it returns a list.

`[ { jack: [ 'shark', 'turtle', 'otter' ], content: 'ocean'},  { marie: [ 'shark', 'turtle', 'otter' ], content: 'ocean' },
  { james: [ 'shark', 'turtle', 'otter' ], content: 'ocean' },
  { paul: [ 'shark', 'turtle', 'otter' ], content: 'ocean'} ]`

Comment: `{ jack: 'jack', content: 'ocean'},
{ marie: 'marie', content: 'pond'},
{ james: 'james', content: 'fish biscuit'},
{paul: 'paul', content: 'cake'}
` 

is not an object. Do you want to get an array as a reponse or an object?

So if you want to get an array, it would be

`
[
  { jack: 'jack', content: 'ocean'},
]
`

Comment: The result you are describing is not an object is an array or multiple objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the role of words array? I think the below code will work.

```
const result = myUsers.map(user => ({
[user.name]: user.name,
content:  user.likes
}));
console.log('result', result);
```

In case, if want to filter the users in word array then below solution will work for you.

```
const result = myUsers.filter(user => {
if (words.includes(user.name)) {
return ({
  [user.name]: user.name,
  content:  user.likes
})
}
return false;
});
```

You can achieve your need with a single loop.

Comment: thanks, this works. I never thought to use the filter prototype.

Answer (score 1):

The answer @aravindan-venkatesan gave should give you the result you are looking for. However important to consider:

When using `.map()` javascript returns an array of the same length, with whatever transformations you told it to inside `map()`.

If you want to create a brand new object, of your own construction.  Try using `.reduce()`.  This allows you to set an input variable, i.e: object, array or string.

Then loop over, and return exactly what you want, not a mapped version of the old array.

See here for more details:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce